# How to update a probability?

Tags: probability

I need to update a system in time. A scanner is giving me probabilities that a single pixel is on:

1. First I got a result with 0.4 probability (that the pixel is on)
2. I got another result with probability 0.7
3. ... another scan ...

How do I combine these? After each scan I would like to have a posterior of what is the probability that the pixel is on. I want to get an answer like 0.6. Because in the beginning I did not have enough evidence (was 0.4), then I am more sure 0.7 but still the 0.4 from before, so I intuitively end up with 0.6 probability that the pixel is on.

How do I model this? How do I do a Bayesian update on this? I need to choose a distribution first and then find a way to update?

Comment: Can you describe what you are need a little more clearly? It's hard to interpret your question. Perhaps providing an example will help.

Comment: yeah this is rather unclear. To me it seems like a standard image denoise problem related to Markov Random Field (often with Gaussian noise).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is specify rigorously what your scanning process returns and the assumptions around it. In other words what does the following really mean?

> I got a result with $0.4$ probability (that the pixel is on)

Does this mean that the scanning process returns only `on` or `off` and you assume/know it has an inherent false negative rate of $40\%$? This would imply that the scanner returned `off` so you deduced that the probability of `on` is $0.4$. This seems like a reasonable model to work with, but then on the second scan you are mentioning probability of $0.7$. The inherent error rate should not change from scan to scan so this model does not seem to fit your description.

Does the scanning process return a number $\in [0,1]$ that denotes its "belief" that the pixel is `on`. What does the belief mean? Obviously it is not the true probability that the pixel is `on` otherwise you'd be done (and moreover it would not change from one scan to another). For example, does the scanner have an insight about the various processes and conditions that affect the scanning and each time it returns the probability  $P(\text{scan is ON} | \text{pixel is ON})$? This seems quite an unlikely feature to have in a scanner, but let's assume it is true for a moment. How would you calculate $P(\text{pixel is ON}| n \text{ scans returned beliefs } B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n)$? Bayes' rule gives us:

$$P(\text{pixel is ON}| n \text{ scans returned beliefs } B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n) = \frac{P(B_1,B_2,\dots,B_n|\text{pixel is ON})\cdot P(\text{pixel is ON})}{P(B_1,B_2,\dots,B_n)}$$

The big question now is what is $P(B_1,B_2,\dots,B_n|\text{pixel is ON})$. If beliefs $B_i$ of concecutive scans were completely independent to each other then this probability would be $\prod_i P(B_i|\text{pixel ON})$. However the scans cannot be completely independent since (at the very least) they are scanning the same pixel, so there is some dependence there. **Edit**: This is not true, at least in theory. You can have two scans (say coming from two different scanning processes) that are independent to each other and still dependent/correlated with the value of the pixel. Of course in practice, this would be hard to claim for scans coming from the same scanner! So to answer this question we need more model assumptions. How are consecutive scans of the same pixel relating to each other?

So, as I wrote in the beginning, you have to be specific and rigorous.